# What is the use for form beans vs form action in struts1?

Tags: struts, struts-1, struts-config

If form bean is used to store the variables of the JSP form connected via `action="submitDetailForm"` for example then what are `ActionForm`s for?

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking; `ActionForm` is a form bean, it's for capturing, validating, and modifying form data.

Comment: In other words, `submitDetailForm` is the `ActionForm`, which is the form bean.

Comment: Thats what I was looking. Whats confusing about the app that I am working on is that it has a form which are actual beans but then a bean folder that parses the request result.

Comment: @bugsaccount In other ways you can't use a form name in the `action` attribute. There should be a mapping to the Struts `Action`.

Comment: @bugsaccount I'm not sure what "bean folder that parses the request result" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Whats confusing about the app that I am working on is that it has forms that are actual beans but there's a bean folder that parses the request result.

Forms are mapped to the action. It doesn't matter which folder they belong. Sometimes classes for the form beans are in the same folder as action beans, sometimes the form beans are in the separate folder. Which folder is used you can find in the `struts-config.xml`.

Everything becomes clear if you read [Struts struts-config.xml action-mapping explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36460054/573032):

> The `type` attribute of the `<form-bean>` is used to enter FQCN of the bean class that would probably extend the `ActionForm`. It's needed by Struts to be able to instantiate a bean when required.

You can also read this article for quick overview of the framework [Struts](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2002/03/newslettermar2002.jsp#struts):

> The `struts-config.xml` file can have several sections. The first section we will look at is the `<action-mappings>` section. `<action>` tells Struts which class to invoke from the `ActionServlet`. Only the `path` and `type` are required entries. The `type` tells Struts which `Action` class to invoke when a URL with the model of the `path` is found.
>
> In order for a class to be entered in the `<action-mappings>` section and to be invoked by `ActionServlet`, it must extend the class `org.apache.struts.action.Action` (see Listing 3). The `ActionServlet` will execute the `perform()` method of the `Action` object. The perform method looks like this:
>
> ```java
> public ActionForward perform(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
> HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
>   throws java.io.IOException, javax.servlet.ServletException
> ```
>
> The `ActionMapping` and `ActionForm` objects will contain information found in the `struts-config.xml` `<action-mappings>` and `<form-beans>` sections. The `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects are from the servlet.